# Why doesn't my code Beep And what code do i use to exit with enter

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm using C++ Assembly Lang Prog x86. I had the project sample code in the beginning and it would say press any key to exit automatically in the end. But then I started editing it yesterday and I got it to let the user input only digits and you pressed any other key it would beep(which is one of the things its supposed to do) But I don't know what happened and now it doesn't exit with the enter key and I can't hear the beep whenever I press a letter or spacebar. This is the code I have

```
.data

enterDigits BYTE    'Only enter digits: ', 0

.code
main PROC

    mov EDX, OFFSET enterDigits
    call WriteString
L1:
    call ReadChar

    cmp AL, 13h
    je FINISHED
    cmp AL, '0'
    jl BEEP
    cmp AL, '9'
    jg BEEP
    call WriteChar
    loop L1

Beep:
    mov AL, 07h

    call WriteChar
    jmp L1

FINISHED:
    call CRLF

    call CRLF

    exit
    main ENDP

END main
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern computers have many things that might affect speaker output. In the old days, basically the only way to stop speaker output was to cut the wires. Check:

- the volume setting on your computer
- that your computer is not muted
- you don't have headphones plugged in (unless you're using them)
- the audio settings on your terminal app
- audio mixer settings

Comment: I've checked all of these things except the terminal app because I don't really know what you mean. I'm using Parallels to do this.

Comment: Oh, if you're doing this in a virtual machine then there are at least double the number of possible settings to check. I can't possibly think of them all, so you'll have to work it out yourself.